# How do I pass in parameters to the Highcharts pointFormatter callback function

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Highcharts has a pointFormatter option that accepts a callback function. I want to use a couple variables in that formatter. How do I do that? Sorry if this is obvious; I'm new to JS. This is what I have so far:

```
chart.addSeries({
      id: "buy1",
      name: "Buys for SD #1",
      type: "scatter",
      color: "#23DA47",
      data: buySellCleaner(buysPoints1),
      tooltip: { 
         pointFormatter: function(priceArr, buysPoints1) {
             return "Time" + "<b>" + unixToEST(this.x) + "</b>" + "<br/>Price: <b>" + priceArr[buySellCleaner(buysPoints1)[this.series.data.indexOf( this.point )][2]][1] + "</b>";
        }
   },
});
```

Obviously priceArr and buysPoints1 aren't defined in the scope...how do I fix that?

Comment: where are `priceArr` and `buysPoints1` defined? It doesn't seem like the callback should have any parameters.

Comment: Right above it. It’s within scope of chart.addSeries

Comment: if they're in the scope of chart.addSeries then they should be in scope for the pointFormatter callback. Try removing them from the callback parameters. `pointFormatter: function() {`

Comment: That worked...thanks!

Comment: no problem, I'll write a slightly more detailed answer for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they're in the scope of `chart.addSeries` then they should be in scope for the pointFormatter callback function.

From the [pointformatter examples](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter) it looks like highcharts does not pass any parameters to the callback.

What you are doing is adding unnecessary parameters to the `pointformatter` callback function and overwriting your previous values for `priceArr` and `buysPoints1` with `undefined`. They are `undefined` because when highcharts calls the pointformatter callback for you, it does not pass any values into the call, so your parameters (priceArr and buysPoints1) are undefined inside the function.

Try removing them from the callback parameters.

```
pointFormatter: function() {
    return "Time" + "<b>" + unixToEST(this.x) + "</b>" + "<br/>Price: <b>" + priceArr[buySellCleaner(buysPoints1)[this.series.data.indexOf( this.point )][2]][1] + "</b>";
}
```