Using class variables inside of highcharts callback functions
I am unable to add to the scope of formatter function the class's scope.
I would like to call
pointFormatter with "this" (the callback scope of formatter in addition to the class's scope since there is a variable that is necessary for me) but when I use the arrow function or use .bind(this) the scope gets replaced completely with the class's scope and then I can't access this.x (I get an error: Property 'x' does not exist on type 'MyService'
Please note, this.urlService is in MyService's scope and this is why I need access to the class's scope.
                    formatter: function (tooltip: Tooltip) {
                        const date = new Date(this.x);
                        const pointString = tooltip.options.pointFormatter.call(this);
                        return `<div>${moment(date).format('MMM Do YYYY')}<br />${pointString}</div>`;
                    },
                    pointFormatter: function (): string {
                        const selectedDate = new Date(Number(this.x));
                        return `<a target="_blank" href=${this.urlService.myUrl}?time=selectedDate>Total Websites: ${this.y}</a>`;
                    }

Bottom line- I'm trying to understand how I can get access to the callback function scope AND the surrounding class's scope. Please let me know if I wasn't clear and thank you.

Just pass an argument to pointFormatter.

What do you mean with "callback function scope" and the "class scope". There is no class here. If there is one I don't suppose you mean the class, but an instance of that class. How do you call formatter? Don't you call it on the instance?

What callback? Nothing here is being called as a callback, not in the code you posted.

@trincot when I do this and change the to pointFormatter: function (url) { I get the error : Type '(url: any) => string' is not assignable to type 'FormatterCallbackFunction'.
Target signature provides too few arguments. Expected 1 or more, but got 0.

You need to both provide the parameter on the one side and the argument on the other side and their types should match.

I think I understand what you are saying, but I'm afraid highcharts does not pass any parameters to the callback. I think they also same the same thing here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51030228/how-do-i-pass-in-parameters-to-the-highcharts-pointformatter-callback-function

I solved my issue by creating a private function I pass my variable into, rather than using the class variable, but I'm still happy to hear other suggestions.
UPDATE: I ended up doing what someone suggested (I thought he meant passing the argument through the call function but I probably misunderstood)
    pointFormatter: ((route) =>
                            function () {
                                                        return `<a target="_blank" href=${route}?time=selectedDate>Total Websites: ${this.y}</a>`;

                            })(this.urlsService.myUrl)

